# Is it possible to pass ArrayBuffer between iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I need to pass large blobs of data between the main page and embedded `iframe`s.
In order to avoid [de]serialization overhead, I would love to pass `ArrayBuffer` with `postMessage()` and instantiate views pointing to this buffer in different `iframe`s.

But it seems that this approach won't work, as MDN docs for `postMessage()` describe `message` parameter as:

> Data to be sent to the other window. The data is serialized using the structured clone algorithm.

This seems to suggest that passing a "pointer" is impossible, as `postMessage()` effectively passes only strings...

Can there be a workaround? Passing *transferable objects* between main and worker threads works great. So does passing `ArrayBuffer` to C/C++ code of *node.js* native extensions.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: In same domain case, wouldn't that be possible by direct assignment to `parent.varname` `iframe.contentWindow.varname` etc. ? Then postMessage() to the target window to notify it to read `varname` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send with your message as partly, and each messages have to two part that data and length when sending message complete  then you can use it other also you should be carefukl is your data really hude then you should use like thread instead of 'for' frame my code ;

**Sender**

**HTML**

```
<button id="send">Send Message</button>
<iframe id="receiver" src="receiver.html" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
var hugeData = '';
var hugeDataLen = 10000003;
var messagePartSize = 500;
function generateHugeData(){
    var i = 0;
    console.log(hugeDataLen / messagePartSize);

    for(i=0;i<Math.floor(hugeDataLen/messagePartSize);i++){
        hugeData += randomString(messagePartSize);
    }
    if(hugeDataLen>(messagePartSize*i)){
        hugeData += randomString(hugeDataLen-(messagePartSize*i));
    }
}
sendBigMessage = function(e) {
    var messagePart = '';
    var i = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < Math.floor(e.length/messagePartSize); i++) {
        messagePart = e.substr(i*messagePartSize,messagePartSize);
        receiver.postMessage({mydata: JSON.stringify(messagePart), len: e.length}, 'http://localhost:10080');
    }
    if(hugeDataLen>(messagePartSize*i)){
        console.log(hugeDataLen-(messagePartSize*i));

        messagePart = e.substr(i*messagePartSize,hugeDataLen-(messagePartSize*i));
        receiver.postMessage({mydata: JSON.stringify(messagePart), len: e.length}, 'http://localhost:10080');
    }
};
function randomString(len) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
var btn = document.getElementById('send');
function sendMessage(e) {
    sendBigMessage(hugeData)
}
btn.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
generateHugeData();
console.log(hugeData);
```

**Receiver**

**HTML**

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

**Script**

```
var data = '';
window.onload = function() {
    var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');
    function receiveMessage(e) {
        if (e.origin !== "http://localhost:10080")
            return;
        messageEle.innerHTML = messageEle.innerHTML + e.data.mydata;
        var jsonData = JSON.parse( e.data.mydata);
        console.log(jsonData);

        data += jsonData;
        if (data.length === e.data.len) {
            alert('complete');
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
}
```

Comment: Ferhat,
Thank you for your detailed answer, but it doesn't help avoiding serialization/deserialization... I was hoping that there's a way to pass a "C-pointer" to an ArrayBuffer, so that the underlying data can be accessed from different contexts directly, without copying...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects) [objects](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/transferable-objects-lightning-fast/). You'd have to call [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#options) like this:

```
iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage(buffer, { transfer: [buffer] });
```